# How to scroll a textView in Right to left direction?

Tags: android, scroll, textview, horizontal-scrolling

After adding a big string in textview,how to scroll back to the initial part of the string??
i am using following textview

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
```

how to make it scroll right to left??

Comment: any help will be appreciated....

Comment: by calling `View#scrollBy` / `View#scrollTo`

Comment: can u elaborate more plz....am new to android.....??

Comment: new or not new, read the docs of those methods and everything will be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scroll" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textViewId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="your_big_string"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In you activity.java, add this

```
final HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);

scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
    }
}, 100L);
```

Comment: it scrolls in default direction i.e left to right...but i want to scroll my text from right to left

Comment: i did.....but the result is same i.e it scrolls from left to right....u try it urself with my given textview in the question....may be it will help you better understanding of the problem....

Comment: The edited ans serves the purpose you asked for. didn't you remove singleline, gravity, layout_gravity from your textView? these attribute may cause problem in your case. I suggest you **not** to edit your textView according to my answer, just copy+paste the sample code and see if it works.

Comment: then you should add your whole xml and describe your needs more specifically (ex: why the gravity is so important?).

Comment: this is my whole xml ;).....i m creating a textview which starts adding text on press button from right side dats why gravity is important to me.after some presses the textview's text goes out of the screen.datts why i need a scroller which scrolls from right to left

Comment: It's getting more complicated to understand what you are asking for. I'm giving up, may be someone else can help you. All the best.